# Problem with RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}, backreference not dispaying in final URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, backreference, query-string

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route\=product\/category\&path\=35\&page\=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/product/category/35/page_$1? [R=301,L]
```

It's not behaving as expected though, when I enter the URL:

```
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=35&page=2
```

It gets rewritten to:

```
http://example.com/product/category/35/page_
```

Could someone tell me what I have done wrong please?

Thanks,

eb_dev

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To reference submatches of a `RewriteCond` directive, you need to use `%n` instead of `$n`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product/category&path=35&page=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /product/category/35/page_%1? [R=301,L]
```