# htaccess rewrite GET request to another GET request

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite the following URL:

```
http://mysite.com/app/checkout/success?token=2V5W&PayerID=WBBQER
```

to

```
http://mysite.com/app/index.php?url=checkout/process/2V5W/WBBQER
```

This rewrite is only needed for GET request of the format (/checkout/success?token=xx&payerID=xx), where both **"token"** and **"payerID"** are fixed parameters.

I'm also including my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

I've been trying countless .htaccess possibilities to no avail so your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't have enough time to write an answer, but the idea is that you make a RewriteCond that describes the format of parameters you want. (analyze the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable). Then do the rewrite. This answer should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703821/problem-with-rewritecond-query-string-backreference-not-dispaying-in-final-u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^token=([^\&]+)&PayerID=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^app/checkout/success$ http://mysite.com/app/index.php?url=checkout/process/$1/$2 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Great, this works like a charm! Just had to change the '$1' and '$2' to '%1' and '%2'. By the way, the "token" variable might have dashes (-) in it. Will those be detected as well?

Comment: Yes. This will work with dashes too because the regex will match anything that is not an & character. Don't forget to upvote if you are happy with this solution :)